# Difference between `TimeoutException` and `CancellationException`

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

According to Javadoc, [Future.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-),
throws `TimeoutException` and `CancellationException` along with 2 others.

Whats the difference between `TimeoutException` and `CancellationException`?

From what i know, `CancellationException` is thrown when the thread timed-out and thus the executor cancelled it. But then when is `TimeoutException` thrown? 
is there a case that the timed-thread timed-out and not cancelled?

saw [CancellationException when using ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517943/cancellationexception-when-using-executorservice) and [What is the best way to handle an ExecutionException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437890/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-an-executionexception) ampng others.

TIA.

//---------------

UPDATE

does nayone else call `Future.cancel()` unless the developer explicitly does?

[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) isn't mentioning anything about `CancellationException` caused by it.

i've got a code coming into the system and i may have to cancel that code due to certain time-limit. but then, i gotta be able to tell when `Future.cancel()` returns true, it did so because the task is completed or it is cancelled. 
From what it seems, `Future.cancel()` is returning true in both of these cases. `Future.isDone()`or any other of its methods are of no help.

Answer (score 4):

> From what i know, `CancellationException` is thrown when the thread timed-out and thus the executor cancelled it.

No.  `CancellationException` is thrown if the `Future`'s `cancel()` method is invoked before the task completes, and either of its `get()` methods is subsequently invoked.

> But then when is TimeoutException thrown?

`TimeoutException` (not `CancellationException`) is thrown by `Future.get(long, Timeunit)` if the specified amount of time passes without the task completing.

> is there a case that the timed-thread timed-out and not cancelled?

Yes.  Timing out is not at all the same thing as being cancelled.

---

Regarding the update:

> does nayone else call `Future.cancel()` unless the developer explicitly does?

Only someone who has a reference to the particular `Future` in question can invoke its `cancel()` method.  The `ExecutorService` does not invoke it, if that's what you mean, and in particular, a timeout differs from a cancellation and therefore does not cause `CancellationException`s.

> javadoc isn't mentioning anything about `CancellationException` caused by it.

The Javadoc for *`Future.cancel()`* does not mention it, nor do I see a particular need for it to do so.  [The exception's own class-level javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CancellationException.html) explain its significance, and the javadocs of those methods of `Future` that can throw it document that they do.

> i've got a code coming into the system and i may have to cancel that code due to certain time-limit.

So it sounds like you would invoke the two-arg version of `Future.get()` so as to specify a time limit, and then in the event of a timeout (signaled by a `TimeoutException`) you would invoke `Future.cancel()`.

> but then, i gotta be able to tell when `Future.cancel()` returns `true`, it did so because the task is completed or it is cancelled. From what it seems, `Future.cancel()` is returning true in both of these cases.

Where do you get that?  The docs of `Future.cancel()`, which you yourself referenced, say that the method returns

> `false` if the task could not be cancelled, typically because it has already completed normally; `true` otherwise

Thus, if `Future.cancel()` returns `true` then you can be confident that the task whose eventual result is represented by the `Future` has successfully been cancelled, in the sense that no result will ever be produced, and that subsequent invocation of one of its `get()` methods will throw a `CancellationException`.  If it had not yet been started then it never will be; if it had been started, then it was interrupted.

The latter alternative requires passing `true` to `Future.cancel()`, and in that case, the task actually stopping depends on its implementation having that response to its thread being interrupted.  It is unclear whether cancellation of an in-progress task is considered successful if the task does not actually stop running; this may in fact be implementation-dependent.

Comment: thx for the useful answer. i've got more behind this Q-- failed to ut it all down before. pls see my update.

Comment: @ash__999, I've updated my answer to respond to your additions to the question, but please be aware that we frown on such question updates here.  This is not a discussion -- once you receive an answer to your question, any followup question ought to be posed as new questions, preferrably referencing the original.

Answer (score 1):

CancellationException is thrown when the task is cancelled, by calling [cancel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-).

TimeoutException is thrown when you ask `get()` to wait for a given time for the result, and the result takes more than that time to be produced.

A thread doesn't time out. And an executor doesn't cancel threads.

Answer (score 0):

> From what i know, `CancellationException` is thrown when the thread timed-out and thus the executor cancelled it.

No, not quite.  If thread A is calling `future.get()` and another thread B calls [`future.cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) then the `future.get()` throws `CancellationException` for thread A.  The exception is trying to tell thread A that the job that it was waiting for was canceled.

> But then when is `TimeoutException` thrown? is there a case that the timed-thread timed-out and not cancelled?

No.  If thread A calls `future.get(long, TimeUnit)`, the method throws `TimeoutException` when the specified timeout expires. It does *not* mean that the running job timed outm just that the thread A that was waiting for the job to finish timed out.  The future is most likely still running.

> does anyone else call `Future.cancel()` unless the developer explicitly does?

Uh this is highly situation dependent.  It is somewhat unusual for someone else aside from the thread that started the jobs to call `future.cancel(...)` but certainly not unheard of.

> I've got a code coming into the system and i may have to cancel that code due to certain time-limit. but then, i gotta be able to tell when Future.cancel() returns true, it did so because the task is completed or it is cancelled.

`future.cancel(...)` returns true if the job was canceled.  To quote from the javadocs:

> Returns: false if the task could not be cancelled, typically because it has already completed normally; true otherwise

So if it returns true then the job successfully was canceled.  You can make sure by calling `future.get()` afterwards which should throw `CancellationException`.

It is also very important to realize that threads can't be canceled easily if they are already running.  Even if you call `future.cancel(true)`, this only interrupts the thread which doesn't stop it immediately.  It will cause `Thread.sleep(...)` and other methods that throw `InterruptedException` to throw but typically you have to write code to obey the interrupt flag.  Something like:

```
// keep running until we are interrupted
while (!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
    ...
}
```